# Ignore specified rows when using `count`/ `sum` with `groupby` but retain the index as a group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a means of ignoring specified rows when using `count`/ `sum` with `groupby` but to retain the index as a group?

For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp


data = {
    "date": [
        Timestamp("2020-06-03 15:00:00"),
        Timestamp("2020-06-04 15:00:00"),
        Timestamp("2020-06-05 15:00:00"),
        Timestamp("2020-06-06 15:00:00"),
        Timestamp("2020-06-07 15:00:00"),
        Timestamp("2020-06-07 15:00:00"),
        Timestamp("2020-06-08 15:00:00"),
    ],
    "score": [1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1],
    "name": ["a", "ignore", "ignore", "d", "e", "f", "g"],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

summary = df.groupby(["date", "name"])["score"].agg(["sum", "count"])
```

Returns:

```
date,name,sum,count
2020-06-03 15:00:00,a,1,1
2020-06-04 15:00:00,ignore,0,1
2020-06-05 15:00:00,ignore,0,1
2020-06-06 15:00:00,d,2,1
2020-06-07 15:00:00,e,1,1
2020-06-07 15:00:00,f,2,1
2020-06-08 15:00:00,g,1,1
```

but I want it to return:

```
date,name,sum,count
2020-06-03 15:00:00,a,1,1
2020-06-04 15:00:00,ignore,0,0
2020-06-05 15:00:00,ignore,0,0
2020-06-06 15:00:00,d,2,1
2020-06-07 15:00:00,e,1,1
2020-06-07 15:00:00,f,2,1
2020-06-08 15:00:00,g,1,1
```

i.e. not including the rows that have a `name` of `ignore` towards the `count` or `sum` but still retaining the date.

Answer (score 0):

### Retroactive Approach

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you can perform the aggregation exactly as you have, but then just change the "ignore" rows to 0 afterwards:

```
summary = df.groupby(["date", "name"])["score"].agg(["sum", "count"])

if "ignore" in summary.index.get_level_values("name"):
    ignore_subset = summary.xs("ignore", level="name", drop_level=False)
    summary.loc[ignore_subset.index, :] = 0

print(summary)
                            sum  count
date                name
2020-06-03 15:00:00 a         1      1
2020-06-04 15:00:00 ignore    0      0
2020-06-05 15:00:00 ignore    0      0
2020-06-06 15:00:00 d         2      1
2020-06-07 15:00:00 e         1      1
                    f         2      1
2020-06-08 15:00:00 g         1      1
```

### Proactive Approach:

Instead of including the ignore rows in the `groupby` we'll first create the expected index, as if we had included the "ignore" rows in the aggregation operation. Once we have this index, we can filter out the ignore rows and perform the groupby operation on the remainder. Lastly, we `reindex` the dataframe to our expected index and fill the `NaN` values (which corresponds to the "ignore" rows) with 0.

```
# Create expected aggregation index
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[["date", "name"]].drop_duplicates())

summary = (df.query("name != 'ignore'")           # filter out "ignore" rows
             .groupby(["date", "name"])["score"]  
             .agg(["sum", "count"])               # perform groupby/aggregation on remainder
             .reindex(index, fill_value=0))       # add "ignore" rows back in filling values with 0

print(summary)
                            sum  count
date                name
2020-06-03 15:00:00 a         1      1
2020-06-04 15:00:00 ignore    0      0
2020-06-05 15:00:00 ignore    0      0
2020-06-06 15:00:00 d         2      1
2020-06-07 15:00:00 e         1      1
                    f         2      1
2020-06-08 15:00:00 g         1      1
```

Comment: If there isn't a means of specifying values to filter out of the aggregation, that may have to do.

However, if there aren't any `ignore` values in the dataframe, will your proposed solution not throw a `KeyError`?

Comment: I appreciate I could catch it, it just feels by that stage a little hacky.

Comment: I added a proactive approach to my answer and updated my original approach, hopefully one of them has a good feel to it and feels less hacky!